# Problem trying to save my google sheet as a pdf to my drive folder

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

1. The script works properly as it should  when i use it from my gmail acc
2. but when I share it to another gmail ACC the script keeps getting errors!
3. The error `Exception: Access denied: DriveApp.`

I use this code to save a specific sheet to my drive as a pdf and mail it to a specific person.
I want the code to run normally when other users are granted permission to use this sheet. Please help me solve this problem.

```
function sendReport(range) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Customers").hideSheet();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Products").hideSheet();
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SO Log").hideSheet();
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SOF").hideSheet();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SOSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Order");
  var name = SOSheet.getRange('F10').getValue();
  

  var message = {
    to: "random@gmail.com",
    subject: "Sales Order",
    body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the Sales Order attached.\n\nThank you",
    name: "Dave",
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("SO"+name)]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Customers").showSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Products").showSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SO Log").showSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("SOF").showSheet();
  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Order");
  var bogus = DriveApp.getRootFolder();


  //Creating an exportable URL
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/exSOrt?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());
  var folderID = "1KU7ylGsci9qsVzxU2ZlCW"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var SOcode = ss.getRange("'Sales Order'!F10").getValue()
  var pdfName = "SO" + SOcode;
  

  /* Specify PDF exSOrt parameters
  From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
  */
  var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'        // exSOrt as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A4'                       // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&SOrtrait=true'                    // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=true&source=labnol'           // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id
    
  // Convert individual worksheet to PDF

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},muteHttpExceptions:true});
    
    
  
  ;
  

var blobs = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');


var folders = folder.getFoldersByName(pdfName);
folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : folder.createFolder(pdfName);


var newFile = folder.createFile(blobs);
var newFileLink = newFile.getUrl();
var SOcode = ss.getRange("'SOF'!F12").getValue();
var writePDFLink =  ss.getRange("'SOF'!L1").setValue(newFileLink);

  
  // Define the scope
  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

}
```

Comment: Is it a Gmail account or Google Workspace account that you are sharing the project or script?

Comment: its a  gmail account

Comment: I think is the access permission to the particular folder, what are the permissions? Do you have it anybody with the link or directly shared with the original gmail? Try opening the permissions of the folder.

Comment: i have set the permission to 'anybody with this link'. Is there any other place to change permission settings ?

Comment: That should be the correct one, at least for the "1KU7ylGsci9qsVzxU2ZlCW", however the one I am wondering is affecting, is the particular one you are calling, the line "  var bogus = DriveApp.getRootFolder();" is it the same from the ID?

Comment: actually i just it added because i got it from an answer from a similar question. but it did not solve my problem. i also deleted and ran the code did not make much difference same error

Comment: Did you set the permission to  'anybody with this link' can view or can edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The method [createFolder(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfoldername) requires `Editor` permissions

- A `Viewer` will receive a `Exception: Access denied: DriveApp` error.
- Thus, you need to share the file with Editor permissions:

---

[image]

Comment: Wow, I did not see that option before! It works now. Thank you for the tip Brother.